# Prove set equality using truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. I have to prove that $A = B$ by proving that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ and I can prove this using truth tables.

For convenience sake, let $P = x \in A$ and $Q = x \in B$.

I have constructed the following truth tables for:

- $A \subseteq B$:
  $$
  \begin{array}{cc|c|c|}
  \text{P} & \text{Q} & \text{$\neg$P} & \text{P $\Rightarrow$ Q } \\
  \hline
  F & F & T & T \\
  F & T & T & T \\
  T & F & F & F \\
  T & T & F & T
  \end{array}
  $$ 
  $\\$
- $B \subseteq A$:
  $$
  \begin{array}{cc|c|c|}
  \text{P} & \text{Q} & \text{$\neg$Q} & \text{Q $\Rightarrow$ P } \\
  \hline
  F & F & T & T \\
  F & T & F & F \\
  T & F & T & T \\
  T & T & F & T
  \end{array}
  \\
  $$

However, I am left confused as to how that proves that $A \subseteq B$, $B \subseteq A$, and ultimately $A = B$.

I understand that for $A = B$ the column $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $Q \Rightarrow P$ must be equal. And they're not — assuming that the order of which $T$s and $F$s appear matters.

I appreciate all help.

Comment: To be more specific, you have a _bunch_ of statements $P_x$ and $Q_x$; one for each $x$. In order to prove $A = B$, you need to prove that both $P_x\implies Q_x$ and $Q_x\implies P_x$ is true _for each_ $x$. To get back to what you were trying to say about the columns being equal, you have to prove that as far as _our specific_ $A$ and $B$ are concerned, the two columns are equal. In other words, there is no $x$ that takes us to one of the two middle rows.

Comment: "I understand that for A=B the column P⇒Q and Q⇒P must be equal. And they're not" $\rightarrow$ They are equal iff the second and third lines cannot be reached, i.e. $(P,Q)\neq (T,F),(F,T), \forall x$. Note that this logical rewriting has not brought you any closer to a demonstration, you have just formulated the problem in a more complex way.

Comment: I conclude from your answers that when there is no mention of a set's elements, it is in my best interest to omit the second and third. In other words, list them separately rather than together. Right?

Comment: @AndyPass I recommend you read the great book *Logic, Sets and Recursion* by Robert Causey. It can help you understand many fundemantal concepts of informal and formal proof. On the other hand, the thoughts of your proof, no matter correct or wrong, is in semantics way, which is not the way we often do. We use syntactical ways(in other words, you can't see truth table in a mathematician's proof). Just read that book to see the difference.

Comment: If what you'd learned is using truth table(i.e., semantics way) to prove every mathematical theorems, then you're on the wrong way. Btw, what book are you reading now?

Comment: @Eric I will definitely take a look at the book, thank you for that. And I was actually reading 'Basics of Compiler design' by Torben Ægidius Mogensen and got confused on solving set equations, so I instead decided to first dive deeper into set theory and stumbled across lecture notes regarding an introduction to logic and set theory and in it there was an exercise where I had to prove that $A = B$ where $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ must be satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that:

> $A=B$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ *and* $B \subseteq A$.

However, as indicated in the comments, your tables don't show $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, so you can't really use the above.

Fortunately, the tables do show the truth-value of $x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$ and $x \in B \rightarrow x \in A$ for some arbitrary $x$.

SO, let's rephrase set identity in terms of elements:

> $A = B$iff for all $x: x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B$

And that is the same as:

> $A =B $ iff for all $x: (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \land (x \in B \rightarrow x \in A)$

So ... do you now see what you need to do?

Comment: I understand. Thank you!